# How can I make a pcolor figure from some easy equations?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following functions, where `x`, `y` stand for positions, and `c` stands for depths or heights. I need to make a `pcolor` figure of `x`,`y` and `c`, but a MATLAB error stops me. This is the code:

```
t= linspace(0,100,1001);
x = t;   
y = cos(pi * t + pi);   
c = cos(pi * t);    
pcolor(x,y,c);    
shading flat;
```

**Error message**

> Error using pcolor (line 53)Color data input must be a matrix.

**New question**

If I want to get a `pcolor` figure like the one below, how to expand `c` to the neccesary matrix?

[image: pcolor figure]

Comment: The error is fairly straightforward: you have to input *matrices*, not vectors. `c` must be a matrix of `numel(x)*numel(y)` size.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I know this reason, but I don't know how to correct my matlab code to make a pcolor from scattered points, that is how to translate c to the neccesary matrix.

Comment: you do not make a `pcolor` from _scattered_ points. `pcolor` takes a matrix as input. If `x` and `y` coordinates are supplied they should form a grid, as created by `meshgrid` (or `ndgrid`). Even if that is corrected, the equation you provide do not yield a figure like in your example. The equation must be different.

Comment: I can't figure out the formula you use for `c` from just looking at your picture. You'd have to provide that equation, which would depend on both `x` and `y` and plot that as `c` matrix

Answer (score 1):

```
t= linspace(0,100,1001).';
x = t;   
y = cos(pi * t + pi);   
ctmp = cos(pi * t);    
c = repmat(ctmp,1,numel(t));
pcolor(x,y,c);    
shading flat;
```

Two changes: I transposed `t`, because column vectors are generally used more than row vectors. Secondly, I used [`repmat()`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to expand your vector `c` to a full-fledged `t*t` matrix, so `pcolor` can plot it.

Figure:

[image: pcolortest]

Strictly speaking they're not *scattered* points, but a line-vector. All I did  is replicate that line `t` times, to it becomes a full matrix with each column being exactly the same, hence the variation in the plot is only in the `y` direction, not in `x`.

Using @Hoki's suggestion:

```
t= linspace(0,100,1001).';
x = t;   
y = cos(pi * t + pi);   
[T,Y] = meshgrid(t,y); C=cos(pi * T); pcolor(T,Y,C);
shading 'flat'
```

results in:

[image: pcolor2]

To get a circle:

```
x=linspace(-100,100,2001);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x);
Z = X.^2+Y.^2;
pcolor(X,Y,Z)
shading 'interp'
```

results in a circle, since `Z = x^2+y^2` is your general formula for a circle:

[image: pcolorcircle]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the pcolor is too flat,  are there any other ways to expand the vector c?  E.g., If I want to see some circles in the pcolor, how to do?

Comment: you can use `meshgrid` to get a base grid from your original vectors. May be `[T,Y] = meshgrid(t,y); C=cos(pi * T); pcolor(T,Y,C);`